# Комплексный json-ответ в spring boot с помощью jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, mvc, jackson

Пишу spring mvc. Для отправки json использую view (id, name, phone) и jackson. После выполнения запроса в service (например, после save) нужно отправить пользователю результат вида `{"data":{"id":1}}`. Либо `{"data":{"result":"success"}}`. В общем что-то в data. Это может быть набор параметров. Наверняка есть какая-нибудь аннотация для класса, которая указывает на класс-обёртку, формирующего в data нужный результат? Буду благодарен за подсказку или ссылку. В интернете гугглил, но мало что понял

**model Users**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    /**
     * Иия
     */
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String Name;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;
    /*...getter, setter...*/
}
```

**view UserView**

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class UserView {
    @ApiModelProperty
    public Long id;

    public String Name;

    public String phone;
}
```

**controller UserController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/user", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Api(value = "UserControllerAPI")
public class UserController  {
/*...service  т.д....*/
    @ApiOperation(value = "addUser", nickname = "addUser", httpMethod = "POST")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", 
response = User.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Failure")})
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = {POST})
    public void addUser(@RequestBody UserView userView) {
        userService.save(userView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог @ControllerAdvice

Сделал так:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class JSONResponseWrapper implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {

@Override
public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class converterType) {
    return true;
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType, Class selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
    if (body instanceof List) {
        return new Wrapper<>((List<Object>) body);
    }

    return new WrapperObj<Object>(body);
}

@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
@JsonSerialize
private class Wrapper<T> {
    private final List<T> data;

    public Wrapper(List<T> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
@JsonSerialize
private class WrapperObj<T> {
    private final Object data;

    public WrapperObj(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
}
```

И теперь return объекта или коллекции объектов в любом контроллере проекта  оборачивается в Data.

Тем не менее спасибо Uraty за полезную информацию. Буду знать про аннотацию @JsonRootName

Answer (score 0):

При запросе "Jackson wrapper object" выдает первой же ссылкой.

Вам нужна аннотация `@JsonRootName`. Копирую оттуда пример, чтобы ответ был более полным:

Пишем так:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "User")
public class UserWithRoot {
    public int id;
    public String name;
}
```

Тогда вместо такого:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John"
}
```

Мы получим это:

```
{
    "User": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John"
    }
}
```

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то это то, что вам нужно.